# How to display records from SQL through menu, using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, menu

i have made a static drop-down menu for my e-commerce website. i have various categories and then sub categories.
my main tabs are, "CLOTHES", "FOOTWEAR", "ACCESSORIES" etc.
The clothes tab is divided into two parts one is brand wise and one is type(shirts, jeans, etc.)
Now my question is, if i go to the clothes tab and then click on shirts, how can i traverse and retrieve the records from my SQL table.
I have made the connection with the database, my table name is 'products'. The page to display products is list.php.
I am new to PHP and i know a little bit about this language.

Comment: If you want to understand what you are doing, I suggest you to start by reading the PHP documentation or at least a basic PHP+MySQL tutorial, there are lots of them all over the internet.

Comment: Php db based menu script : http://hiox.org/33272-php-db-based-menu-script.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a pages table and categories table

also have cat_parent in the categories table
Then have a php loop to go through each topmost categories and then subcats and ......... and then pages.

watch it in action [this is the site i am working a the moment](http://trekintonepal.com)

Answer (score 0):

First you should have categories & sub categories in single 'categories' DB table. 
In products table, you will have a category_id column as foreign key. 
So based on this category_id column, you can retrieve products from your DB.
Also each product in DB should have assigned a particular category.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX or a Javascript function to achieve this type of functionality. Here is how:

1. Use an `onChange` event in your static drop down menu HTML code.
2. Make a function in a `<script>` tag to catch the id of selected item.
3. Pass this id to the PHP file in the URL.
4. Give your `<div>` id name in this Javascript code.
5. After calling the PHP file catch the id from get method and pass it to the query.
6. You can get the desired result.